# Powershell script to view all OneDrive files and who has access to them

Tags: powershell, office365, onedrive

I'm pretty new to PowerShell and wanted to know if there was a way to pull all files from OneDrive and see who has access to them?

I was hoping to find an easier way to see whether or not a file is shared and if it is, who is it shared with internally and externally.

As of right now, I know if you go through each user account, you can see this information.  I'm curious to know if there is a faster way to that.

Answer (score 2):

You can call OneDrive [List Shared File](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/shared_by_me.htm) Rest API to finish the job.

You need register an application to get proper access to your OneDrive according to https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm

Then you can make use the code below.

```
$ClientId = "<Your application client id>" # your application clientid 
$SecrectKey = "<Your application key>" # the secrect key for your application 
$RedirectURI = "<Your web app redirect url>" # the re-direct url of your application 

Function List-SharedItem 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$ClientId, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$SecrectKey, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$RedirectURI 
    ) 

    # import the utils module 
    Import-Module ".\OneDriveAuthentication.psm1" 

    # get token 
    $Token = New-AccessTokenAndRefreshToken -ClientId $ClientId -RedirectURI $RedirectURI -SecrectKey $SecrectKey 

    # you can store the token somewhere for the later usage, however the token will expired 
    # if the token is expired, please call Update-AccessTokenAndRefreshToken to update token 
    # e.g. 
    # $RefreshedToken = Update-AccessTokenAndRefreshToken -ClientId $ClientId -RedirectURI $RedirectURI -RefreshToken $Token.RefreshToken -SecrectKey $SecrectKey 

    # construct authentication header 
    $Header = Get-AuthenticateHeader -AccessToken $Token.AccessToken 

    # api root 
    $ApiRootUrl = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0" 

    # call api 
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Header -Method GET -Uri "$ApiRootUrl/drive/shared" 

    RETURN $Response.value 
} 

# call method to do job 
$Results = List-SharedItem -ClientId $ClientId -SecrectKey $SecrectKey -RedirectURI $RedirectURI 

# print results 
$Results | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host "ID: $($_.id)" 
    Write-Host "Name: $($_.name)" 
    Write-Host "ParentReference: $($_.parentReference)" 
    Write-Host "Size: $($_.size)" 
    Write-Host "WebURL: $($_.webUrl)" 
    Write-Host 
}
```

For complete instructions, you can see the sample in https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-use-OneDrive-Rest-5b31cf78